# How many solutions there are of $y'=2x(y^2-1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How many solutions there are of $$y'=2x(y^2-1)$$
if the initial value $y(0)=2$

I could get only two solution

Comment: Have you tried solving it? The equation is separable.

Comment: I think the separable not enough to find all solutions

Comment: It depends on how you want to characterize the answer. As I hope you can see, we can find an infinite number of solutions. That is probably enough.

Comment: I don't understand, it should be only one solution due to the Uniqueness and Existence Theorem.

Comment: The differential equation not linear

Comment: Please show the two solutions you got.

Comment: @Did $|1-\frac{2}{1+y}|=Ce^{2x^2}$ $\rightarrow 1-\frac{2}{1+y}=\mp Ce^{2x^2}$

Comment: And $y(0)=2$ hence $\mp C=$ $____$ and $y(x)=$ $____$. Sorry but where are the two solutions (not to mention six)?

Comment: @Did $C=\mp 1/3$

Comment: $\mp C=1/3$ would be more correct. Anyway, this makes for **a unique solution**, not for two or six.

Comment: @Did but this equation not linear

Comment: And so what? Linear differential equations are not the only ones to have a unique solution for some given initial condition.

Comment: @Did ok what do you say about the solution y=1 this satisfy the equation

Comment: With the initial condition $y(0)=2$? I don't think so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19247/discussion-between-ehegh-and-did).

Comment: @Did I think there is another solution y=-1

Comment: You are not paying attention hence this is my last comment: no, $y(x)=-1$ for every $x$ is not a solution to the differential equation $y'(x)=2x(y(x)^2-1)$ with the initial condition $y(0)=2$.

Comment: @Did Sorry Sorry

Comment: The answer is: **one solution**, by the existence/uniqueness theorem.

Comment: @Ehegh I just said this above.

Comment: yes , you are right

Comment: Now that the dust has (seemingly) settled, let me mention that to invoke the existence of two solutions and then, despite some direct prodding to provide these, to never do so, is rather bizarre (and we shall not mention the 3 upvotes, shall we?).

Comment: @AaronMaroja In a too tentative way, starting with "I don't understand" and "should"... with the effect that the comment did not get through to the asker. This is why I felt the need to **state it boldly**.

Comment: @Behaviour You did right! I need to be more like that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Separating variables:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{y^2-1} = 2x \mathrm{d} x$$
Then integrating:
$$\int \frac{1}{(y-1)(y+1)} \mathrm{d} y = x^2 + C$$
Next:
$$\int \frac{1}{(y-1)(y+1)} \mathrm{d} y = \int \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{y-1} - \frac{1}{1+y}\right) \mathrm{d} y = \frac{1}{2} (\ln{|y-1|}-\ln{|1+y|})$$
Therefore we get:
$$ \ln{\left|\frac{y-1}{1+y}\right|} = 2 x^2 + C$$ and the rest is easy:
$$\left|\frac{y+1-2}{1+y}\right| = C e^{2x^2}$$
And hence:
$$\left|1-\frac{2}{1+y}\right| = Ce^{2x}$$
I hope I didn't do any mistake and I hope you will be able to derive $y$ from the last equation.

$y(0)=2$ then $\left|1-\frac{2}{3}\right| = C = \frac{1}{3}$. So you get a single solution with $C = \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: I think you forgot the absolute of |ln(  )|

Comment: it should be vice versa: $\ln{|\ldots|}$

Comment: I have given the initial value

Comment: @Behaviour this initial condition appeared there after I wrote my solution. Edited it.